# iOS indexPathsForSelectedRows and initial selection

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

[image: When I enter editing mode][image: Before entering editing mode]

I have a UITableView which shows features for a product with a checkmark shown on the right of the cells for the supported features. The app allows the user to check more features or to uncheck others and for get that the UITableView enters editing mode with multi-selection mode on. The problem is that I would like to set the already checked features (in order to let the user uncheck them), but indexPathsForSelectedRows is readonly and I could not find a way to initialize some rows, so that they are already selected when the grid enters the editing mode. Is there a way to get that result? Any help would be much appreciated.

The pictures show the 2 situations. When the table view is not in editing mode I have the checkmark accessories. When the table view enters editing mode, with  multi-selection enabled, it shows the checkboxes...but they are all unchecked and I cannot programmatically check them... or at least that is what it looks like

Comment: "The app allows the user to check more features or to uncheck others and for get that the UITableView enters editing mode with multi-selection mode on."  Come again?

Comment: Like command-clicking files in finder.. @ElTomato

Comment: The idea is to have the grid entering in editing mode with multi-selection having a few cells already selected. The default is that all cells are unchecked ... that is not good for me, I need to check a few cells before entering editing mode so that they look already checked in order to let the user uncheck them at will. Hope now it is more clear. Thank you

Comment: so you have multi-selection working already?

Comment: Yes, the multi-selection is working fine... except for the fact that at the beginning all cells are unchecked

Comment: Answer incoming...

Comment: @Sergiob If you want help then you need to show us what you have try, add the code of tableView methods

Comment: I just added 2 pictures to better show the situation ... I hope

Comment: @Sergiob That will not help to understand what you have try, you need to show us your code that you have try.

Answer (score 0):

If checkmark is a selection style, you can try to use

`tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)`

in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method

Answer (score 0):

OK... in the end I found a way. My UITableView had selection disabled in normal mode and multi-row selection enabled in editing mode... to fix the problem it is enough to override

```
override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {

        super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)

        tableView.selectRow(at: ....., animated: true, scrollPosition: .none)
    }
```

And select there the rows I want checked in editing mode.
That would solve the problem. Thanks to all of you who have tried to help me...